# /home/biol/perl5: Is a directory

Tags: bash, shell-script, perl

the below script crashed:

```
#!/bin/bash
#usage: sh oxford_pbs.sh ref.fa AA.fasta hybrid.gff3

cov=50
ide=100


for ((i=70;i<=${ide};i++));
do
  input=$(basename $(echo ${2} | sed 's|.gff3||g'))

  #cat <<EOF
  qsub <<EOF
#!/bin/bash -l

#PBS -N filter
#PBS -l walltime=20:00:00
#PBS -j oe
#PBS -l select=1:ncpus=1:mem=30G
#PBS -M m.lorenc@qut.edu.au
##PBS -m bea

cd \$PBS_O_WORKDIR
module load bioperl/1.7.1-foss-2017a r/3.4.2-bioconductor-foss-2017a
eval "$(perl -I$HOME/perl5/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib)"

agat_sp_extract_sequences.pl --gff ${2}-ide${i}-cov${cov}-best-hit.gff3 -f ${1} -p -o ${2}-ide${i}-cov${cov}-best-hit.AA.fasta
EOF
done
```

with this errror:

```
/var/spool/PBS/mom_priv/jobs/8352088.pbs.SC: line 24: /home/biol/perl5: Is a directory
/var/spool/PBS/mom_priv/jobs/8352088.pbs.SC: line 27: agat_sp_extract_sequences.pl: command not found
```

However, these two commands run without any problems on command line:

```
> module load bioperl/1.7.1-foss-2017a r/3.4.2-bioconductor-foss-2017a
> eval "$(perl -I$HOME/perl5/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib)"
> 
> agat_sp_extract_sequences.pl --help

 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   Another GFF Analysis Toolkit (AGAT) - Version: v0.1.0                      |
|   https://github.com/NBISweden/AGAT                                          |
|   National Bioinformatics Infrastructure Sweden (NBIS) - www.nbis.se         |
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Why does the Perl script does not run inside the Bash script?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `$(perl ...)` command substitution will be done immediately, since you have `qsub <<EOF` rather than `qsub <<'EOF'` in order to have `${i}` expanded.

The perl will output lines that can contain spaces, like

```bsh
PERL_MB_OPT="--install_base \"/home/user/perl5\""
```

but by the time you eval these in the execution of the final script it will become

```
PERL_MB_OPT=--install_base "/home/user/perl5"
```

and you will the error about `/home/user/perl5` is a directory.
The simplest solution is to defer the perl until later:

```
eval "\$(perl -I$HOME/perl5/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib)"
```